# How to Debug "Too Deeply Nested" error

Tags: nesting

I see that numerous people have asked a similar question.  At the risk of annoying you LaTeX experts, the problem is, as I have expressed before, that LaTeX is a truly awful language.  Having said that, someone who is a reasonably competent programmer in Java/C++/Perl/Python etc ought to be able to debug a program that stops working.

Currently, the only way I have to debug a failure is to either quickly undo if I have luckily only written a few lines, or to comment out blocks of code until I identify the region where the problem is.  This is completely unacceptable.  If that's the only way, then the language is at fault.  I am looking for any help in how to find an error WITHOUT having to edit hundreds of lines.

I compile my code and the console given an error on line 709:

```
\materials
\begin{itemize}
\item photoresistor (3k)
\item resistor (2.2\kohm)
\end{itemize}
```

The \materials command is defined as:

```
\newcommand{\materials}{{\bf Materials:}}
```

The item with photoresistor is the one giving the error.  Presumably this means that there are unclosed \begin{itemize} commands before?

Q1:  What are the possible causes of this error.  Could there be any OTHER unclosed entity causing it? What about \begin{enumerate} ?

Q2: How can I find it, aside from searching every \begin{itemize} and manually looking for the matching \end{itemize}

Q3: Is there any code I can write to assert that everything must be closed, or to display the location of any open \begin?  This would go a long way towards solving this problem!!!

Comment: “Too deeply nested” means you are starting a seventh level nested list. I've seen this caused by improper usage of `\quote` or similar; are you perhaps using `\flushleft` or `\flushright`?

Comment: The language isn't really at fault if it gives errors on bad input. the standard classes only allow itemize to be nested 6 times, so it is impossible to debug that from the fragment shown, perhaps you have that many nested lists or perhaps you have a bad definition generating lists to arbitrary depth. note `\bf`  is deprecated and not defined by default (although unrelated to your error), there is lots of additional traing you can turn on in the log `\tracinggroups=1` for example will give more info on groups, `\tracingall` gives more info on _everything_

Comment: one debugging approach you can take is to place `\end{document}` just before the cited `\materials` line, and run the job.  at the end of the log, it will tell you at what "level" you finished on, if it's not zero.  *always* look for this in a log, and close any open levels before adding more to the file.  it will save you much grief later on.

Comment: In the emacs editor using AUCTeX you can type `C-c ]` to close the current environment, and so discover which environments are currently open.

Comment: It turns out that a command I thought was closing was not closing, but the question here is not about the error, but rather how to find it.

Comment: Well you found it, what did you do? (hard to give advice other than the very general comments already given, without seeing the error)

Comment: +1 for emacs, \end{document} comments, they seem like useful strategies that I will try.  I use TeXWorks but for debugging I will do whatever it takes

If you post these as answers, I would pick one as an answer.  At least its something.

Comment: Some editors (e.g. texstudio) highlight the corresponding `\end{itemize}` to a `\begin{itemize}` or the lack thereof, thus its easy to see if something is missing. And for "having to edit hundreds of lines": use and editor with block comment functionality - this makes such task easy as cake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you suspect that you have unclosed groups then let TeX get to the end, or if other errors stop tex or obscure the problem, add `\stop` at a point that you want to test, and look at the terminal output or log.

So for example

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

aaa

\begin{itemize}
\item xxx
\item xxx
\end{itemize}

bbb

\begin{itemize}
\item xxx
\item xxx
%oops\end{itemize}

bbbb

\begin{itemize}
\item xxx
\item xxx
\end{itemize}



\stop



more stuff here

other \ERROR we are not concerned about
```

If you run the above, TeX stops at the `\stop` and the terminal output shows

```
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 14 (\begingroup)
```

so the level 1 means that you have exactly one extra open group and the second line tells you that it's a semi simple group, which means it is started with `\begingroup` not `{` so in latex most likely started by `\begin`

then it tells you it started on line 14 which is exactly the

```
\begin{itemize}
```

line for the list with the missing `\end`.

Comment: The error message you get with `\end{document}` instead of `\stop` is even more informative: `\begin{itemize} on input line 14 ended by \end{document}.`

Comment: @egreg that makes it too easy:-)