# Unexpected and probably wrong "Too deeply nested" error with De Gruyter template

Tags: errors, lists, enumerate, debugging

I'm using the De Gruyter template for the PETS conference, here is a [direct link](https://petsymposium.org/files/popets.zip) (ZIP). I'm getting a "Too deeply nested" error, and relevant searches only led to "reasonable" reasons why I could get this error (lists with more than 7 levels of nesting, or trailing open environments). Here is a minimal working example that shows that the problem must be elsewhere:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{prop}{\protect\propositionname}

\usepackage[big]{dgruyter_NEW}
\usepackage{babel}
  \providecommand{\propositionname}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{prop}
woo prop
\end{prop}
\begin{prop}
woo prop
\end{prop}
\begin{prop}
woo prop
\end{prop}
\begin{prop}
woo prop
\end{prop}
\begin{prop}
woo prop
\end{prop}

\begin{prop}
woo prop
\begin{enumerate} % this is where it fails
\item woo item
\item woo other item
\end{enumerate}
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

The weird thing is that deleting one of the dummy `prop` environments *fixes the problem*: I don't get the error anymore. Maybe the `\end{prop}` lines aren't taken into account or something?

Online, people suggest to add the lines:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlistdepth{9} % or some bigger number
```

This technically works (no more errors, if I set it to 30 for my article), but the placement and indentation of `enumerate` or `itemize` environments is all wrong:

[image: bullet points on the right column end up in the left column, and indentation is wrong]

Finally, I tried the debugging technique in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/314754/136193) and added a `\stop` right before the `\begin{enumerate}`. The output seems correct, but not consistent with the "too deeply nested" error:

```
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)
### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 32 (\begingroup)
```

Comment: `dgruyter_NEW` file loads `amsthm` already

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're unfortunately bound to using a buggy package. `:-(`

You can fix the error by loading the package before defining new theorems.

It's usually better first to load packages and then doing setup, in general. The style file loads `amsthm` and provides the `dgthm` and `dgdef` theorem styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[big]{dgruyter_NEW}

\theoremstyle{dgthm} % not plain
\newtheorem{prop}{\protect\propositionname}
\providecommand{\propositionname}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{prop}
woo prop
\end{prop}
\begin{prop}
woo prop
\end{prop}
\begin{prop}
woo prop
\end{prop}
\begin{prop}
woo prop
\end{prop}
\begin{prop}
woo prop
\end{prop}

\begin{prop}
woo prop
\begin{enumerate} % this is where it fails
\item woo item
\item woo other item
\end{enumerate}
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but unfortunately not for my workflow, since I'm using LyX and I can't easily add something *before* the part of the preamble that is automatically added by LyX. It seems I have to go [create my own layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354284/inserting-code-before-lyx-generated-preamble) to avoid this =/

Comment: @Ted I don't consider LyX as a good tool for writing in LaTeX, sorry.

Comment: Additionally, it seems that even without the LyX shenanigans, loading `dgruyter_NEW` before `amsmath` or even not `amsmath` at all (like your example) isn't enough to make this bug go away. I've written [another minimal example](https://pastebin.com/raw/uAtgiSPp) that raises the same error.

Answer (score 4):

the package doesn't work with `amsthm` lodaed first (it loads `amsthm` but modifies some definitions later).

But changing the three lines marked makes it more or less work (the first line is an unrelated problem that has come up before, the redefinition of `\p@` used by this package completely breaks latex, I am surprised to see the package still being distributed with that in)

```
$ diff dgruyter_NEW.sty~ dgruyter_NEW.sty
22c22
< \p@=1bp
---
> %NO!!!!!!\p@=1bp
1379c1379,1380
<   \global\advance\@listdepth\@ne
---
> %NO  \global
>   \advance\@listdepth\@ne
1391c1392,1393
<   \global\advance\@listdepth\m@ne
---
> %NO  \global
>   \advance\@listdepth\m@ne
```

Comment: People at DG know better than you. `;-)`

Comment: Thanks David. Unfortunately, this works on my minimal example, but not on my article. I've created a [second minimal example](https://pastebin.com/raw/mA3CRbvs) that fails even when I apply your changes.

Comment: @Ted sorry but the package is a commercially supported package from De Gruyter and really it just breaks far too much stuff, I suggest you contact the maintainer listed in the comments in the file. But in any case for publication you should probably use the theorem forms provided by that package rather than use amsthm directly.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is a bad interaction between `dgruyter_NEW` and `amsthm` packages. If you import the `dgruyter_NEW` first it should work.