Error while using \include{} or \import{} -- After 7 \include{} or import{}, I get "Too deeply nested"
I am trying to write my thesis and I arranged the chapters and their materials in various folders. I am including them to my main document using the \import{} or \include{}. There is no problem until I reach to chapter 7. Everything works great until I want to add more than 7 chapters. After chapter 7, I get the "Too deeply nested" LaTeX Error. I would be grateful for any help. Thank you so much in advance!

If you drop the first 6 chapters, do you still get the error?

I guess you have in chapter 7 some list with a sublist with a subsublist with a subsubsublist and so on at an insane level of nested lists. But without any code, it is only a guess.

Welcome to TeX.SE One of my project, I could remember that I've included 46 chapters using \include tag without any issues, so it might be error in that particular chapter only, please check that particular chapter alone by using \includeonly

Your error is probably not due to including or importing chapters but to some error in your code. Maybe you are forgetting to close \enumerate or \itemize. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314685/how-to-debug-too-deeply-nested-error for example. Try each chapter separately to see what happens.

You have shown no code and only shown a small fragment of the error message, That makes it hard to help. Assuming it is the standard latex \@toodeep error it is unrelated to \include and relates to list nesting.
